# Multiple align points with a single equation number

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, alignat

I have the following equation:

```
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
     &\phantom{{}={}} [ (1,1,1) : (1,1) : (1,2) : (1) : (2,2,2) : (2,2) : (2) :  (3) ] \\
     \textsc{one} &= [ 0 : 3 : 0 : 0 : 0 : 0 : 0 : 0 ] \\
     \textsc{two} &= [ 1 : 0 : 3 : 0 : -1 : 0 : 0 : 0 ] \\
     \textsc{three} &= [ 0  : 0 : 3 : 0 : -1 : 0 : 0 : 0 ] \\
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the opening `[`, each `:`, and closing `]` aligned vertically to match the top row.

I have tried various combinations of align, alignat, equation, alignedat, but I am unable to find anything that works.

Any pointer would be appreciated.

I tried the alignedat from other answers:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{alignedat}{9}
     &[ (1,1,1) &: (1,1) &: (1,2) &: (1) &: (2,2,2) &: (2,2) &: (2) &:  (3) & & ] \\
     \textsc{one} = &[ 0 &: 3 &: 0 &: 0 &: 0 &: 0 &: 0 &: 0 & &] \\
     \textsc{two} = &[ 1 &: 0 &: 3 &: 0 &: -1 &: 0 &: 0 &: 0 & & ] \\
     \textsc{three} = &[ 0  &: 0 &: 3 &: 0 &: -1 &: 0 &: 0 &: 0 & &] \\
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
```

but it doesn't actually seem to do the alignment (only aligns some :'s).

[image]

Comment: Number of & should be 2x9-1 on each line. 9 & to mark alignments and 8 & to mark the separation between alignment columns (and alignment column is two columns with and alignment & between them). See it as a large table where the columns are grouped into pairs. In your case you can probably get by using && in many places as the corresponding left part of those alignment columns are empty

Answer (score 3):

You can use `autoaligne`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{autoaligne}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\definirseparateurs{\\}{}{:||[||]}
\autoaligne[*d]{
                  [\, (1,1,1) : (1,1) : (1,2) : (1) : (2,2,2) : (2,2) : (2) :  (3) \,] \\
\textsc{one}={}   [\, 0 : 3 : 0 : 0 : 0 : 0 : 0 : 0 \,] \\
\textsc{two}={}   [\, 1 : 0 : 3 : 0 : -1 : 0 : 0 : 0 \,] \\
\textsc{three}={} [\, 0  : 0 : 3 : 0 : -1 : 0 : 0 : 0 \,]
}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\definirseparateurs{\\}{}{:||[||]}
\autoaligne[*c]{
                        [\, (1,1,1) : (1,1) : (1,2) : (1) : (2,2,2) : (2,2) : (2) :  (3) \,] \\
\hfill\textsc{one}={}   [\, 0 : 3 : 0 : 0 : 0 : 0 : 0 : 0 \,] \\
\hfill\textsc{two}={}   [\, 1 : 0 : 3 : 0 : -1 : 0 : 0 : 0 \,] \\
\hfill\textsc{three}={} [\, 0  : 0 : 3 : 0 : -1 : 0 : 0 : 0 \,]
}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this one the best, but you mention in another question that it is quite a new package. If it cannot be used in arXiv submissions I think that rules it out for me - plus I couldn't find any English documentation. Is there any way to get them centered like in (2) but in a arXiv compatible way?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use an array

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{array}{r<{{}}@{[}r@{:}r@{:}r@{:}r@{:}r@{:}r@{:}r@{:}r@{]}}
     & (1,1,1) & (1,1) & (1,2) & (1) & (2,2,2) & (2,2) & (2) &  (3) \\
     \textsc{one} = & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
     \textsc{two} = & 1 & 0 & 3 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
     \textsc{three} = & 0  & 0 & 3 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a correct code with `alignedat`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{alignedat}{9}
     &[ (1,1,1) & & : (1,1) & & : (1,2) & & : (1) & & : (2,2,2) & & : (2,2) & & : (2) & & : (3) & & ] \\
     \textsc{one} = {}&[ 0 & & : 3 & & : 0 & & : 0 & & : 0 & & : 0 & & : 0 & & : 0 & &] \\
     \textsc{two} = {}&[ 1 & & : 0 & & : 3 & & : 0 & & : -1 & & : 0 & & : 0 & & : 0 & & ] \\
     \textsc{three} = {}&[ 0 & & : 0 & & : 3 & & : 0 & &: -1 & & : 0 & & : 0 & & : 0 & &] \\
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a TABstack.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \setstacktabbedgap{3pt}
    \tabbedCenterstack[r]{
     [& (1,1,1) :& (1,1) :& (1,2) :& (1) :& (2,2,2) :& (2,2) :& (2) :&  (3) & ] \\
     \textsc{one} = [& 0 :& 3 :& 0 :& 0 :& 0 :& 0 :& 0 :& 0 &] \\
     \textsc{two} = [& 1 :& 0 :& 3 :& 0 :& -1 :& 0 :& 0 :& 0 & ] \\
     \textsc{three} = [& 0  :& 0 :& 3 :& 0 :& -1 :& 0 :& 0 :& 0 &]
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]